# Error 500 while usingWeb-Hooks w/ Gitlab and Gitlab-Auto-Deploy

Tags: git, gitlab, autodeploy

When I try to send a POST request with GitLab everytime my repo is pushed to my production server running GitLab-Auto-Deploy, I get a 500 error. I followed the indications in the README file (http://logsol.github.io/Github-Auto-Deploy/) but I still get this 500 error.

Did I miss something ? Is there anything more to set up ? I just want GitLab-Auto-Deploy to pull my master branch and then say "server up to date".

**Info** :
A `wget http://prod-server.com:1337` from the GitLab server works fine, and the GitLab-Auto-Deploy answer me (saying that a GET request is not supported). GitLab server runs Debian Squeeze, GitLab 6.1 w/ nginx.

Thx for your help

Comment: I get exactly the same issue, and I'm investigating it now. I shall update you if I find the cause of the problem.